# Magento Tax - Custom calculation

Tags: php, magento

I have products added to my Magento store with 20% tax included.

I have a store view that is shown to USA customers.

I require the price to remain the same, but hide the Tax in the cart/orders. Also I need to double the tax and show it, if they are in the USA but their shipping address is not.

Examples:

- Normal price £10 (inc £2 tax)
- USA price: $10 (no reference of tax/$0 tax)
- USA price but shipping to another country: $12 (inc $2 tax)

I have the prices working as required, I just need some help as to where I can hide the tax and also double it depending on shipping country.

Answer (score 1):

In Magento admin, in the Promotion menu, there are the so called "Shopping Cart Tax Rules" and "Catalog Price Rules". Here you can set taxes to Countries, Customers, Categories, etc.

Also in System->Configuration->Taxes (if I remember well) there are some settings regarding the display of taxes.

Have you tried any of these?

Comment: Hi @Nethuns - Yes I have tried all of these but it doesn't do what I require. Catalog price rules apply to the entire website, there's no way to do it per store view.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that line and I have no more ideas.